libdecor-gtk-WARNING: Failed to initialize GTK. Occurs when using glfwinit
I have a testing project set up for bgfx.
Problem is, i can't get GLFW to initialize properly.
The code snippet currently existing is this:
#include <bgfx/bgfx.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

#define WINDOW_WIDTH 1920
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 1080

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Initializing GLFW\n";
    glfwInit();

    std::cout << "Creating window\n";
    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);

    std::cout << "Initializing bgfx\n";
    bgfx::init();

    std::cout << "Exiting" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

The console execution is this:
cmake . && make && valgrind --leak-check=full --log-file="yay.log" ./BGFX_Testing

-- Configuring done (0.0s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/entropy/CLionProjects/BGFX_Testing
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/BGFX_Testing.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable BGFX_Testing
[100%] Built target BGFX_Testing
Initializing GLFW
libdecor-gtk-WARNING: Failed to initialize GTK
Failed to load plugin 'libdecor-gtk.so': failed to init
Creating window
Initializing bgfx
Exiting

Notes:
If needed i can provide the CMakeList.txt and the valgrind yay.log (1055)
The only question I have found with a similar issue is this, which has no verified answer, one answer that seems useful, which didn't change my problem.
OS Info:

Kernel: 6.6.34-1-MANJARO
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5700X (16) @ 3.400GHz
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon RX6700XT

Any Idea on what i could do to solve this issue?
Things I have tried already:

Checking libdecor installation

sudo pacman -S libdecor

Checking libdecor dependencies

ldd /usr/lib/libdecor-gtk.so
(all installed)

Installing GLFW-X11 and -Wayland (Each alone or both at once, didn't change the issue)

sudo pacman -S glfw-x11 sudo pacman -S glfw-wayland
EDIT:
Because of some other issues, I have changed reinstalled my OS and changed my Kernel to 6.10.0-3-Manjaro.
The issue discussed in this Post is no longer existent, although I still don't know how and why it existed in the first place.

I found that starting a program from VSCode (ex. from terminal or in a debug mode) makes my GLFW not link to libdecor for some reason.
My VSCode is not installed through flatpak or any other encapsulating package mangager, just AUR.
To launch a program properly all you need is to run it from a regular terminal.

why do you use cmake and building like from console not by mouse clicking? could you try Rider or other IDE, where you can see compiler arguments, probably there is an absent about linked libs, check there example of such lib arguments, they must be present in output. smth like '-l lfilename.so'
Link .so file to .cpp file via g++ compiling

You can use CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE to see the explicit CLI steps used by CMake, which I currently don't need. The issue you are hinting at however would be noticed by the linker as it needs all statically and dynamically linked libraries to be present in link-time to ensure that all bindings are working correctly.
Why don't I use mouse clicking: I like not having to move my hands constantly between mouse and keyboard when coding. Hotkeys possibility to quickly switch between editor and I can do changes to the build process or similar relatively quickly. Its is a personal preference.
